# Laravel ajax is not returning success data

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to achieve a functionality, If I select a category in dropdown, then in next dropdown, subcategory of that chooces category will appear. I wrote below ajax in script tag for it.

```
$("#category").change(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var category = $("#category").val();

    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:"{{ route('ajaxRequest.post') }}",
       data:{category:category},
       success:function(data){
        alert(data.success);
        $("#subcategory").replaceWith(data.subcats);
       }
    });

});
```

Here is my route setup for the same

```
Route::get('add_product', [dashboardController:: class, 'addProduct']);
Route::post('add_product', [dashboardController::class, 'getSubCategories'])->name('ajaxRequest.post');
```

This is my controller function

```
function getSubCategories(Request $request){
    //$input = $request->all();
      
    $subCategoryList = DB::table('ajax_categories')->where('pid', $request->post('category'))->get();
    $sub = '<option desabled selected>Choose sub category</option>';
    foreach($subCategoryList as $subCategory):

        $sub .= '<option value="'.$subCategory->id.'">'.$subCategory->category.'</option>';

    endforeach;
    return response()->json(array(
        'success' => 'Success',
        'subcats' => $sub
    ));
}
```

Everything seems fine, I am not getting what causing it to be fail.

Screenshot of network tab

[image]

On clicking on checkbox, I got this in reponse

[image]

Comment: Also , you need parse json before accessing it so use `dataType:"json"` as an option in your ajax .

Comment: You're not passing `csrf_token()` with your post request. [Refer to here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI I have used token in form. Also add it in ajax saperately like this `$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });`

Comment: @swati It is not even showing alert msg which is written just before your mentioned line. SO this means success msg is not returning

Comment: @Rishabh.is request hitting to server ?. check network tab and also verifiy category  has value before ajax call

Comment: check your network tab then press submit button that error add here then you will get your solution .

Comment: @JohnLobo its showing this in metwork tab `add_product 419 xhr vendor-all.min.js:1 12.2 kB 381 ms`. On click on checkbox it shows this ` "message": "CSRF token mismatch.",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
    "file": "D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\elab\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
    "line": 387,` @RakeshkumarOad

Comment: then its csrf token issue.may ajax setup not set proeprly .check headers passed in request. try once  data:{_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",category:category}, or check met csrf is set in header

Comment: @JohnLobo Hi, with your last suggestion, values started to come in network tab. I can see returned subcategory data in network tab. But on success, my typed alert and code to add html is not working. Have any idea on it please?

Comment: what you get in network tab response .can you show screenshot or result

Comment: @JohnLobo Screenshot added in post. Pls check.

Comment: @Rishabh.are you echo in controller method before json return then remove echo

Comment: @JohnLobo Ohh I did echo for testing purpose. Removed and and it is working fine now. So actual solution for me was your suggestion of using csrf with data like this `{_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",category:category}` instead of my choocen method for csrf. Please post this as answer. I will accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are echoing result before returning response so ajax is not able to parse json properly.And other is `csrf token` not passed properly.
In ajax you can pass csrf token like below

```
data:{_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",category:category},
```

instead of appending in controller better do like this

```
function getSubCategories(Request $request){

   $subCategoryList = DB::table('ajax_categories')->where('pid', $request->post('category'))->get();

    $view=(string)view('dropdown',['subCategoryList'=>$subCategoryList])
    return response()->json(array(
        'success' => 'Success',
        'subcats' =>$view
    ));
}
```

in your view **dropdown.blade.php** you can

```
   @if(isset($subCategoryList)&&count((array)$subCategoryList))
        
    @foreach($subCategoryList as $key=>$value)
        
    <option value="{{$subCategory->id}}">{{$subCategory->category}}</option>
    
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: I tried this approach of your, It seems simpler than my chosen method but it is not working in my case. But your this suggestion `{_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}` with my code worked perfectly fine. –

Comment: oaky.but it should work. any way you have solved your issue

Comment: initial post i forgot @endif in view so .updated later

Comment: You didn't add your comment suggest of passing csrf with data like this `data:{_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",category:category},` in your answer which actually solved my issue. Thats why I didn't accept answer yet :)